# best way to add file way to my pythpath.which can be saved

Tags: python

```
import sys
print sys.path

sys.path+=['D:\\zjm_code']
print sys.path
```

it can't be save,how does do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where is environment variable `PYTHONPATH` defined in your working environment?

In Unix-like systems it would be in a bash script such as `~/.bashrc`.

In Windows it could be a `.BAT` or `.CMD` file but more often will be in the registry.

"Saving" a setting of `PYTHONPATH` to a file is easy.

Writing to the Windows registry is *much* harder, alas.  Doable, yes, but, if you get it in the least wrong, you're likely to make your whole machine unusable.

In your `site-packages` directory (which should itself be in `sys.path`) you can create a file named `sitecustomize.py` that is automatically imported, if it exists, each time a Python program starts.  I suggest that this is simpler and less risky than messing with the registry.  So, write your `sys.path` manipulations to such a `sitecustomize.py` file.

Answer (score 0):

you can use append()

```
import sys
sys.path.append("/mypath")
```

to save it permanently, you can export PYTHONPATH in the user shell initialization file (eg .bash_profile)

```
PYTHONPATH=/path/to/module/directory:/path/to/module2/dir2
```

on Windows systems, you can follow instructions [here](http://docs.python.org/using/windows.html).

Comment: Indeed, @zjm, it's just a simpler way to do _exactly_ the same job as your `+=`.